# Dash in Unity-2D: how to tweak search?

Tags: unity-dash, unity-2d, search

For some reason after recent update Unity-2D dash doesn't show programs: I type "firefox" but it shows only files and folders as shown on the following image:[image: dash doesn't see Firefox]

However dash finds Firefox after pressing the second icon at the bottom of the Dash window, as shown on the following image:[image]

What I want is to be able to launch programs "in a few seconds" without using the mouse. Ideally, by typing "<kbd>Super</kbd>firef<kbd>Enter</kbd>". I have tried to find a dash manual using Google, but have failed to find anything useful.

Is there any way to tweak the Dash in such a way that "<kbd>Super</kbd>firef<kbd>Enter</kbd>" would launch Firefox, "<kbd>Super</kbd>term<kbd>Enter</kbd>" would launch the terminal and so on?

Is there any Dash manual, suggesting how to tweak it?

**Update:** after another Ubuntu update and subsequent reboot the problem has disappeared. So I think the question can be closed. However I'm still interested in Dash manual, describing, how to tweak Dash. So if someone has an idea on where to find one, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt + F2 brings up "Run a Command" in the dash. You can start typing "firefox" and press Enter to launch it.